# How to empty data of TCP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I implemented a client - server application uses TCP protocol.
The client side is implemented in c++, cannot be changed. I am writing server side in c#.
(In this case the client sends to the server the data and the server handles the data)
The communication flows well in most of cases.

In case of receiving a large amount of data, I have the following problem: The window size is full and I get only partial data. I follow the communication by `WireShark`, which mark the last received package as [TCP Window full] and the next receive as [TCP zero window].

I understand the issue here is the limitation of the stream size.

Trying to increase my `Socket.ReceiveBufferSize` solve the problem, but I do NOT want to use it, since the amount of data is very dynamic and I have no way to know it before.

I am looking for a way to EMPTY the socket from the received data which I have already read.

Does anyone know a way to do it?

Please see my code below:

```
public static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    allDone.Set();
    Socket listener = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(asyncResult); 
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    string content = String.Empty;
    StateObject state = (StateObject)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        if (handler.Connected)
        {
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            //Is there a way delete here the read bytes from socket??? 
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                if (/*end of expected data*/)
                {    
                }
                else
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
                allDone.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("waiting for re-connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), listener);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }

}
```

Comment: You usually get a zero window when the buffer is full and cannot accept any more data.  The data is cleared from the buffer when you read it.  There isn't any way I'm aware of to flush the read buffer.  Once the data has been read, the window will open and it will accept data again.  The EndReceive will return any bytes read up to the size you stated in the BeginReceive (StateObject.BufferSize), so you need to keep reading.  In TCP your not guaranteed to get all the data in a single read.  Did you trace the callbacks and make sure you are continuing to read until you get all the data?

Comment: Of course I have some reads. You can see that if '/*end of expected data*/' condition is false, I call handler.BeginReceive() again. But after the buffer size limitation (as I caught it) it does not get there again. Something else I can mark is that I have no exception in my code, I just see that no all the expected data has read.

Comment: I would put some console writes in the code to debug (maybe print the content variable each time through), the issue has to be somewhere other than what you think it is. My bet is that the if condition isn't doing what you expect.  I don't know why you believe there's a buffer issue if you don't have any exceptions.  The code is basically off of Microsoft's Async example.  I can't imagine the Stringbuilder (state.sb) has any limitations, so the if condition is really the only other logical place.

Comment: Thank you very much! My condition was really true before the end of data, what stopped the reading continuation... The unread packages, for this reason, were marked as non-received [Zero window] in WireShark.